# Object alloc init irregularities

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm seeing some disturbing irregularities concerning object allocation and initialization in an app I'm trying to write.

I have a 'root' Modelcontroller object, which in turn contains references to subcontrollers. The root controller is called modelController, and in it's init method it allocates and inits the subcontrollers like so:

```
- (id)init
{
NSLog(@"%@", @"ModelController begin init");
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    LibraryController * tempLibrary = [[LibraryController alloc] init];
    self.library = tempLibrary;

    StoresController * tempStores = [[StoresController alloc] init];
    self.stores = tempStores;

    CLLocationManager * tempLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager = tempLocationManager;

}

NSLog(@"%@", @"ModelController complete init");

return self;
}
```

Pretty standard. The subcontrollers' init code also contain an NSLog messages at the beginning and the end, for me to be able to see that all is well.

The properties are defined as

```
@property (strong) LibraryController * library;
@property (strong) StoresController * stores;
@property (strong) CLLocationManager * locationManager;
```

And I am using ARC.

What puzzles me is that sometimes I see the NSLogs from one of the subcontrollers, but not from the root controller. Sometimes I see the 'begin init' log message from the root controller, but not the 'complete init'. Sometimes I see no init log messages. The application launches anyway in any of these cases.

This happens seemingly at random, in one out of five launches or in one out of twenty launches. When it happens, the app acts very strange (but not every time, mind you), beachballing for no apparent reason and exhibiting general wonkiness.

As a side note, at one time I put a breakpoint in the init method of the StoreController class, which when pausing executing spit out a chunk of random data in the debugging console:

> $m2303,3503,3603,3703,3803,3903#00$m2303,3503,3603,3a03#00$88ee410901000000981e420901000000001e42090100000060ee410901000000b062f668ff7f000070044391ff7f0000f00e0800000000000300000068200100dc62f668ff7f0000d862f668ff7f00000000000000000000717ddd8aff7f00000000000068200100801e420901000000000000000600000706000007000000007063f668ff7f000003280000000000007863f668ff7f000001ee410901000000f062f668ff7f00006c5bd391ff7f000000000000ff7f0000ab064391ff7f000000000000ffffffff032800000000000040
>   ...and so on

Where should I begin to look to troubleshoot this?

The modelController is alloc init'd from the MyDocument equivalent class, and is modeled as a singleton.

The singleton implementation looks like this:

```
static ModelController *sharedModelController = nil;

+ (ModelController*)sharedManager
{
    if (sharedModelController == nil) {
        sharedModelController = [self new];
    }
    return sharedModelController;
}
```

Final note: I have tried removing the locationManager stuff and disabling/enabling the 'Restore state' preference in the scheme, but to no avail.

Comment: Questions: Are you using ARC? How are the `library`, `stores` and `locationManager` properties defined. Also, `NSLog` is defined as requiring a format statement, not an `NSString` so the correct statement would be: `NSLog(@"%@", @"ModelController: completed init");`.

Comment: Answers to your questions from the OP would be helpful. I just wanted to point out that @"ModelController: completed init" is a valid format statement, and there's nothing wrong with the way his NSLog() calls are written.

Comment: @CocoaFu I updated the post to answer your questions.

Comment: @Andrew Yes and such usage is problematic. Also the code for the other `NSLog` statements is unknown. When things aren't working for me I fix all questionable code first. :-) The fact that there was a bunch of strange output in the console does point to an errant `NSLog` statement.

Comment: @CocoaFu The other NSLog statements are identical to the ones present here, except they say 'LibraryController complete init' instead of 'ModelController'. Even after I changed the NSLog format strings to what you recommend, I get the problem with missing log statements. However, I still haven't been able to reproduce the junk output either before or after the change.

Comment: @CocoaFu, I'd be interested in a link to documentation explaining why `@"ModelController: completed init"` is not a valid format string for passing into `NSLog`.

Comment: @Andrew My previous comment acknowledged that. In general it is a bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're doing some UI stuff not on the main thread.
This generally leads to weird behavior.
Make sure you call everything UI related on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: the `ModelController` object is being released. Perhaps the Singleton is faulty.